# wget: Change to parent folder in ftp server?

Tags: ftp, wget

I need to copy some files from /var/opt/myfiles (in the ftp server) to my local server. So I use wget for the task.

The problem is that the default directory when I log on to the ftp with my username is **/home/jdoe**. So if I wget.exe -nc --user=USER --password=PASS ftp://Myserver.com/var/opt/myfiles*, it correctly tells me that it doesn't exist since 'var' isn't within my user folder /home/jdoe.

I have access to /var/opt/myfiles, so how can I 'tell' wget to move to that folder?

Thanks.

Comment: not sure (I have no server to try it myself), but try with `ftp://Myserver.com/../../var/opt/myfiles*`

Comment: You can't, the ftp server won't allow that. Use sftp, or copy the files to your home directory first.